# Convert String to Date and Time in PHP

Tags: php, string, date, time

I've got a whole bunch of dates and times stored in a mySQL table as simple strings in the following format:

Tuesday, March 15, 2012

6:30 p.m. - 8:00 p.m.

I need a way to convert them into a PHP date and time format.

I imagine I could use explode to get the date format fairly easily but how would I do something similar with the times?

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: suggestion: use the search function because there is already 5000+ other questions asking how to reformat dates

Answer (score 2):

The strtotime function will probably be your best solution here.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
<?php
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
?>
```